# Space between \hline\hline in longtable using package colortbl

Tags: longtable, colortbl

When I use a `\usepackage{colortbl}` a space between `\hline\hline` in `\longtable` dissapears. I haven't find any solution how to put the space back, so I hope you'll help me to find it.

```
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|c|r|r|r|}
        \caption{{ABD}}
        \label{tab:SO}\\
\hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{{SO} - 01} & \multicolumn{7}{ c| }{AD}\\
    \hline\hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{Popis} & MJ & AD & AD & CD\\
    \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{AD }& $3$ & 37000 & 0,32& 11\,800   \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

`colortbl` loads a load of code at `\begin{document}` checking for longtable and ensuring compatibility. If you stop it doing that then things work better. I blame the package authors of the `colortbl` and `longtable` packages for not communicating.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\makeatletter
\let\xx@begindocumenthook\@begindocumenthook
\let\xxhline\hline
\let\xx@xhline\@xhline
\usepackage{colortbl}
\let\hline\xxhline
\let\@xhline\xx@xhline
\let\@begindocumenthook\xx@begindocumenthook
\makeatother
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}\color{black}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|c|r|r|r|}
        \caption{{ABD}}
        \label{tab:SO}\\
\hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{{SO} - 01} & \multicolumn{7}{ c| }{AD}\\
    \hline\hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{Popis} & M J & AD & AD & CD\\
    \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{AD }& $3$ & 37000 & 0,32& 11\,800   \\
    \hline
\end{longtable} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Haven't the authors of `colortbl` and `longtable` got a chance to talk to each other yet? `:-D` Jokes aside, I've run into this very issue recently, and the fix doesn't seem to work any more with TeXlive 2022.

Comment: @campa by coincidence I'm looking at colortbl after many years, looking at adopting the xcolor table extension https://github.com/davidcarlisle/dpctex/commits/main

Answer (score 1):

The `colortbl` package redefines the `\LT@@hline` macro just after the `\begin{document}`, and the first `\ifx` compares the macro `\hline` with the macro `\LT@next`. But the macro `\hline` (inside a 'longtable' environment) expands to:

```
\noalign{\ifnum 0=‘}\fi\penalty\@M\futurelet\@let@token\LT@@hline
```

So the correct is to compare the macro `\hline` and `\@let@token`.

A workaround is to prepend `\let\LT@next\@let@token` to definition of `\LT@@hline`, after the `\begin{document}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl,longtable}
\begin{document}
    \makeatletter
    \let\LT@@hline@bkp\LT@@hline
    \def\LT@@hline{\let\LT@next\@let@token\LT@@hline@bkp}
    \makeatother
    
    \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|c|r|r|r|}
        \caption{{ABD}}
        \label{tab:SO}\\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{{SO} - 01} & \multicolumn{7}{ c| }{AD}\\
        \hline\hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{Popis} & M J & AD & AD & CD\\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{AD }& $3$ & 37000 & 0,32& 11\,800   \\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```