# Space between \hline\hline in `longtable`

Tags: tables, spacing, longtable

I'm trying to use one `longtable` in my thesis while all others are created with `table` and `tabular` environment. 
I tried to find help visiting [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107564/space-between-hline-hline-in-longtable-using-package-colortbl). But there only one type of table (`longtable`) is used.

The first lines (between `%`and `%`) in my preamble are copied from the link above. If I don't use them the code works but at the same time there's no space between the `\hline\hline` anymore. If I only use the `longtable` or put the `longtable` first, the code can be compiled.
But the order represented in this extract represents the order in my thesis.

If I don't use the `colortbl` respectively `xcolor` with the option table it works fine. But I don't know how I can color my rows without using this package. But I need the space between the two lines to separate different categories.

Thanks for your help.

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{color}
\makeatletter
\let\xx@begindocumenthook\@begindocumenthook
\let\xxhline\hline
\let\xx@xhline\@xhline
\usepackage{colortbl}
\let\hline\xxhline
\let\@xhline\xx@xhline
\let\@begindocumenthook\xx@begindocumenthook
\makeatother
\usepackage{longtable}
%
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%
\usepackage{subcaption}
%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings,color}
%
\begin{document}\color{black}
%
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|}
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray}
\textbf{Component} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Flight segment [\%]}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Passenger segment [\%]}} \\ \hline
1 & 20 & 80 \\ \hline \hline
2 & 10 & 90 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption 2}
\end{table}
%
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|p{5cm}|c|p{4cm}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray}
\textbf{Mass component} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Techfactor}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Reason}} \\ \hline
A lot of text & a lot of text & a lot of text \\ \hline
A lot of text & a lot of text & a lot of text \\ \hline
A lot of text & a lot of text & a lot of text \\ \hline \hline
A lot of text & a lot of text & a lot of text \\ \hline
A lot of text & a lot of text & a lot of text \\ \hline \hline
A lot of text & a lot of text & a lot of text \\ \hline
\caption{Caption 1}
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
%
Text text text.
%

% 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `\hline` twice, i defined a new line-type to get it done. A workaround - but providing the desired behavior. This is the code for the new line-type that need to be put into the document/preamble:

```
\newcommand{\lline}[1]{\hline\multicolumn{#1}{c}{}\\[-1.3em]\hline}
```

So instead of `\hline\hline` i used `\lline`.

Answer (score 1):

I did use another trick. I'm German so please apologize for my language. That use of to heads is only important if u wanna continue ur heading on the next pages

```
\begin{longtable}{p{4cm} | p{1.5cm} | p{1.7cm} | p{7.5cm}}
\caption{This is a wonderful caption}\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{ } \\[-1,3em]  %intresting part for ur question
    \hline
\label{tab:wonduferful_longtable}
    \textbf{column 1st header} & \textbf{column 2nd header} & \textbf{column 3rd header} & \textbf{column 4th header} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \textbf{column 1st header} & \textbf{column 2nd header} & \textbf{column 3rd header} & \textbf{column 4th header} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    blabla & blabla & blabla & blabla \\
    blabla & blabla & blabla & blabla \\
    blabla & blabla & blabla & blabla \\
\end{longtable}
```

Answer (score 1):

- If the problem is only drawing `\hline\hline` in a long table, then a simple solution would be `hhline{===}` (in the case of the table with three columns) from package `hhline`
- off topic:

  - It is sufficient to load `xcolor` paclage exclusively, which is supersede of `color` package and its option `table` calls `colortbl`;
  - Long table is default centered, so encapulating it in `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` is superfluous;
  - Captions, especially in the case of long tables, should be on the top of them, not at the bottom;

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\usepackage{hhline}
%
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%
\usepackage{subcaption}
%
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{longtable}{|p{5cm}|c|p{4cm}|}
    \caption{Caption 1}                       \\
   \hline
\rowcolor{lightgray}
\thead{Mass component}  & \thead{Techfactor} &  \thead{Reason}  \\
    \hline
A lot of text & a lot of text & a lot of text \\ \hline
A lot of text & a lot of text & a lot of text \\ \hline
A lot of text & a lot of text & a lot of text \\
    \hhline{===}
A lot of text & a lot of text & a lot of text \\ \hline
A lot of text & a lot of text & a lot of text \\
    \hhline{===}
A lot of text & a lot of text & a lot of text \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
%
Text text text.
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Roboticist -- please restore the code of the example that was originally provided.  it should not be left to a reader to have to reconstruct the details from a description when they were provided by the person who originally answreed.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, i return the code. when approving his editing of my terrible language (well, here 02:15) i not see that he is also deleted my code ..

Comment: i was checking the edit, and thought the grammatical changes were decent, but was rather scandalized that the code was removed.  i was trying to fix it, but couldn't do it fast enough on my laptop -- you beat me to it.  good going.

Comment: @barbarabeeton@Zarko Sorry for the (inadvertent) inappropriate change applied to the code, which was not really what I was intended to do!