# Longtable behaviour of adapted \hline (\nobreakhline)

Tags: tables, longtable

I work with longtables and a workaround with \nobreakhline. Somehow the workaround does not really work as the real \hline if two lines should be put after each other. So I want the same apperance as in the first table with \hline\hline but make use of \nobreakhline.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter
\def\nobreakhline{%
\multispan\LT@cols\unskip\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill\cr
\noalign{\penalty10000}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}}
    \caption{Blabla} \\
    \hline\hline
    8,8 &85,3 &1,4 \\\hline
    8,8 &85,3 &1,4 \\\hline
    \hline
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}}
\caption{Blabla} \\
\nobreakhline\nobreakhline
8,8 &85,3 &1,4 \\*\nobreakhline
8,8 &85,3 &1,4 \\*\nobreakhline
\nobreakhline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

How can this be achieved? 
[Space between \hline\hline in `longtable`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245611/space-between-hline-hline-in-longtable)

Comment: did the answer meet your requirement -- please let us know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking ahead to make  `\hline\hline` is by far the most complicated part of hline, it could be copied to nobreakhline but if you wanted to support things like `\hline\nobreakhline` it gets even worse so I would simply define a second command that makes the double rule, say

```
\def\nobreakhhline{%
\multispan\LT@cols\unskip\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill\cr
\noalign{\penalty10000\vskip\doublerulesp}%
\multispan\LT@cols\unskip\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill\cr
\noalign{\penalty10000}%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for -- the solution has been given by @DavidCarlisle  -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107566/197451

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\let\xx@begindocumenthook\@begindocumenthook
\let\xxhline\hline
\let\xx@xhline\@xhline

\usepackage{colortbl}
\let\hline\xxhline
\let\@xhline\xx@xhline
\let\@begindocumenthook\xx@begindocumenthook
\makeatother

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|c|r|r|r|}
        \caption{{ABD}}
        \label{tab:SO}\\
\hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{{SO} - 01} & \multicolumn{7}{ c| }{AD}\\
    \hline\hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{Popis} & M J & AD & AD & CD\\
    \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{AD }& $3$ & 37000 & 0,32& 11\,800   \\
    \hline
\end{longtable} 
\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}}
    \caption{Blabla} \\
    \hline\hline
    8,8 &85,3 &1,4 \\\hline
    8,8 &85,3 &1,4 \\\hline
    \hline
\end{longtable}
\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}}
\caption{Blabla} \\
\hline\hline
8,8 &85,3 &1,4 \\*\hline
8,8 &85,3 &1,4 \\*\hline
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I do not have a deep understanding of the code inside \makeatletter... However this solution is not able to control the pagebreak via \nobreakhline. Even in Table 3 you only use \\\* so in case of using \hline a pagebreak is allowed.

I want to use both of them (\\\* and \nobreakhline together or \\ and \hline together) at certain positions to allow and completely disallow pagebreaks within the longtable rows.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround with the help from David Carlisle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter
\def\nobreakhline{%
\multispan\LT@cols\unskip\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill\cr
    \noalign{\penalty10000}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\def\nobreakhlinedouble{%
    \multispan\LT@cols\unskip\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill\cr
    \noalign{\penalty10000\vskip\doublerulesep}
    \multispan\LT@cols\unskip\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill\cr
    \noalign{\penalty10000}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{longtable}{p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}}
        \caption{Blabla} \\
        \hline\hline
        8,8 &85,3 &1,4 \\\hline
        8,8 &85,3 &1,4 \\\hline
        \hline
    \end{longtable}

    \begin{longtable}{p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}}
        \caption{Blabla} \\
        \nobreakhlinedouble
        8,8 &85,3 &1,4 \\*\nobreakhline
        8,8 &85,3 &1,4 \\*\nobreakhline
        \nobreakhlinedouble
    \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

At the end it makes a double line in one and then another line. This is better for coding the row input.